# Handling various types differently when using generic methods

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a progam which asks the user for input multiple time while processing data.
In order to make testing easier I've written a MyDelegateFactory that can return a delegate to a consumer.
Since not all data entered is the same a generic method was used.

But now I'm running into the issue that not all, but most, types are handeled the same.

I tried the code below to remedy the exceptions. But I don't think this is a good way to go about things.

```
public MyDelegate<T> GetMyDelegate<T>()
{
    if (typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IMyInterface)))
    {
        return MyInterfaceSpecificDelegate<T>;
    }

    return DefaultMyDelegate<T>;
}
```

So my main question is wether there is a cleaner way to do this, or if I'm better of by having DelegateFactory interface specify all special cases.

Answer (score 0):

As you need to define the actual type on client-side anyway, you can also just create *two* methods, as the two cases are completely independant and have *nothing* in  common. In other words: generics are meant for things that are generic for *all* possible types, not just a few. If you find yourself switching on the provided type, generics are usually not the way to go. Instead just use two functions:

```
public MyDelegate<T> GetMyDelegate<T>() where T: IMyInterface
{
    return MyInterfaceSpecificDelegate<T>;
}
public DefaultMyDelegate<T> GetDefault()
    return DefaultMyDelegate<T>;
}
```